# Integral of the divergence of a vector field multiplied by the component of another vector field

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, integration

In *Forces in Molecules* by Richard Feynman (Phys. Rev. **56**, 340 (1939)), eq. (5) implies that

$$\int(\nabla\cdot \textbf{F})E_\mu^\alpha dv=-\int F_\mu(\nabla\cdot E_\mu^\alpha)dv,$$

being $\textbf{F}$ an electric field, $F_\mu$ its $\mu-$componentand and $E_\mu^\alpha$ the $\mu-$component of another electric field $\textbf{E}^\alpha$. It is claimed that this equality comes out from integration by parts.

Now I've tried to do the following. First, assume $(\nabla\cdot\textbf{F})E_\mu^\alpha=E_\mu^\alpha(\nabla\cdot\textbf{F})$. Then use the divergence identity $$\psi(\nabla\cdot\textbf A)=\nabla\cdot(\psi\textbf A)-\textbf A\cdot(\nabla\psi)$$ from which $$\int(\nabla\cdot\textbf F)E_\mu^\alpha dv=\int\nabla\cdot(E_\mu^\alpha\textbf F)dv-\int F_\mu^\alpha(\nabla\cdot E_\mu^\alpha)dv.$$

I'm not sure these passages are even correct, sorry in advance. Assuming they are so, I can't get why it should be $$\int\nabla\cdot (E_\mu^\alpha\textbf F)dv=0.$$

Comment: You can use the divergence theorem, then if you integrate over all space the integral will tend to zero

Answer (score 0):

What Feyman is *trying* to say is that if ${\bf E}^1$ and ${\bf E}^2$ are two curl-free fields, than
$$
0=\int E^1_\mu (\partial_\nu E^2_\nu)d^3 x+ \int E^2_\mu (\partial_\nu E^1_\nu)d^3 x.
$$
This is a  form of Newton's third law: the first on the first charge distribution ${\bf E}^2\rho_1={\bf E^2}(\nabla\cdot {\bf E}^1)$ due to the second is equal and opposite to the force of the second by the first.  To prove it we integrate by parts to get 
$$
\int E^1_\mu (\partial_\nu E^2_\nu)d^3 x= - \int (\partial_\nu E^1_\mu)E^2_\nu d^3x =  - \int (\partial_\mu E^1_\nu)E^2_\nu d^3x.
$$
At the last step we have used curl-free to say that $\partial_\mu E_\nu=\partial_\nu E_\mu$.
Now do the same for ${\bf E}^1$ interchanged with ${\bf E}^2$. Add the two results we get
$$
\int(E^1_\nu (\partial_\mu E^2_\nu)+ E^2_\nu (\partial_\mu E^1_\nu)d^3x = \int \partial_\mu (E^1_\nu E^2_\nu) d^3x
$$
and the last expression integrates to zero because it is a  total derivative. QED!